# How bulletproof is Rails' stock XSS protection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, xss

In Rails 4.2.4, say I have a form with a text field that a user can input whatever they want.  I don't sanitize the input at all.  The user then submits the form and to a controller method that looks like this:

```
def datahandler
   @data = params[:usersdata]
end
```

Then in the related view, "datahandler.html.erb", I have the following:

```
<%= @data %>
```

Should be a huge XSS vulnerability right?  Well it looks like Rails now automatically converts certain characters in string objects into CDATA representations for their views.  This appears to break at least the XSS attack examples I've found.

However, I'm hesitant to rely on this mechanism without some research as I'm not an expert in XSS vulnerabilities.  Further, the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) don't seem talk about this feature, even in their security guide (they talk about defending against XSS but they don't mention this feature).  I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Can anyone point me to some documentation regarding this feature?  If not, does anyone know of any loopholes in this protection (please provide examples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' stock XSS protection is extremely bulletproof.

The default behavior was [changed in Rails 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html), to "escape HTML output ... by default in all view templates". Although there have been cases where the [escaping needed to be adjusted](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a19ee5cfd35fe85fd065be30de5af6b20363b682), most of the [known XSS vulnerabilities in Rails](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12043/product_id-22568/Rubyonrails-Ruby-On-Rails.html) have [not been centered around this functionality](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rubyonrails-security/xss%7Csort:relevance).

At any rate, the code in your question should be quite secure. The main problem with the current XSS protection in Rails is caused by [developers misunderstanding the mechanics of the process](http://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong). Taking the time to [fully understand the implementation](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) will ensure that you do not inadvertently introduce XSS errors in spite of the built in protection.

Comment: You might be interested in the escape_javascript helper as well. This can come in quite handy from time to time, but is not done by default. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for.  Haven't gotten through many of the CVEs yet, but after reading the articles, I'm feeling much better about the built in XSS protection and my understanding of it.

Comment: @Rossman You're very welcome. I think the main takeaway could be that the view template escaping is quite robust, until you stink it all up with a bunch of raws and html_safes.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm concerned, it doesn't do that by default but it has a protection mechanism which does that for you in case you'd want to use it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection

Comment: [Rails 3+ does do this by default.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html)

Comment: @BradWerth, **ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json now defaults to false.**

Comment: With all due respect, you seem to be confusing several different items.